# delete an issue disabled from GitHub

Tags: github

I opened an issue, and the project disabled the issue feature. Now I want to delete it, but I can't navigate from my profile page to the issue. So how can I delete it or just don't show it on my page?

[image]

Comment: If the issue feature is disabled and you can't navigate to the issue... where are you seeing the issue?

Comment: @Schwern I see it from activity in my profile page

Comment: What do you mean by "disabled"?

Comment: @jhpratt i add a picture. https://help.github.com/en/articles/disabling-issues

Comment: @Kovacs Even if you deleted the issue, the record of your having opened an issue on the project would still be there. Is there a problem with having the issue in your activity stream?

Comment: @Schwern um... so there is some way to don't show it in my activity stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a private repository, [you can turn off publicizing your private contributions](https://help.github.com/en/articles/publicizing-or-hiding-your-private-contributions-on-your-profile).

In my own testing, deleting the issue will remove it from your Contribution Activity. Only the owners of the repository can delete the issue. You will need to contact them and ask them to delete the issue.

Comment: thanks, I have never done this before, and just thought could delete my own opened issue

Comment: @Kovacs The record of the issue is useful to the project, so only they can delete it. It's no biggie if it stays on your activity feed.